# Want to append a column in a file without using the Pandas

Tags: python

I have a file say, `outfile.txt` which looks like below:

```
1,2,3,4,0,0.95
1,2,4,4,0,0.81
5,6,3,1,0,0.89
7,6,8,8,0,0.77
6,6,4,9,0,0.88
9,9,9,1,0,0.66
4,3,6,9,0,0.85
1,2,6,7,0,0.61
```

Now I want to append one extra 1 to each row. So the desired output file looks like:

```
1,2,3,4,0,0.95,1
1,2,4,4,0,0.81,1
5,6,3,1,0,0.89,1
7,6,8,8,0,0.77,1
6,6,4,9,0,0.88,1
9,9,9,1,0,0.66,1
4,3,6,9,0,0.85,1
1,2,6,7,0,0.61,1
```

How can I do it? Whenever I am googling it to find a solution, I am seeing everywhere this kind of solution is provided using Pandas, But I don't want to use that.

Comment: You can use the `csv` module.

Comment: Is Python a requirement, or do you have access to GNU tools?

Comment: @S3DEV Yes, I am using Python, so Python is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just, iterate through the file line by line and add **,1** at the end of each line:

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'r') as input:
    with open('outfile_final.txt', 'w') as output:
        for line in input:
            line = line.rstrip('\n') + ',1'
            print(line, file=output)
```

Comment: Yes, but... this doesn't account for `\r\n` line endings which are the standard for CSV files.

Comment: Yes, but taking into account requirements it works :)

Comment: Actually, taking into account requirements... its not stated either way. The comment is meant as a warning for anyone writing CSVs. Whether it applies to this question is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Since your file is in csv format, [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module can help you. If you iterate over the `reader` object, it gives you a list of the items in each line in the file, then simply `.append()` what you want.

```py
import csv

with open("outfile.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        line.append("1")
        print(",".join(line))
```

If you have a column like `column` you can zip it with the `reader` object and append the corresponding element in the loop:

```py
import csv

column = range(10)

with open("outfile.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line, n in zip(reader, map(str, column)):
        line.append(n)
        print(",".join(line))
```

I printed, you can write it to a new file.

Answer (score 1):

You can read and write files line by line with the `csv` module. A `reader` object will iterate the rows of the input file and `writer.writerows` will consume that iterator. You just need a bit of extra code to add the 1. Using a list generator, this example adds the extra column.

```
import csv
import os

filename = "outfile.txt"
tmp = filename + ".tmp"
    
with open(filename, newline="") as infile, open(tmp, "w", newline="") as outfile:
    csv.writer(outfile).writerows(row + [1] for row in csv.reader(infile))
os.rename(tmp, filename)
```